# path smoother on Galactic branch

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that the path smoother module is only supported by humble version. Is there a way to add this module to galactic branch?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406855/path-smoother-on-galactic-branch/) by [zl3612](https://answers.ros.org/users/27052/zl3612/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Galactic is EOL in roughly 30 days, it is not our intent to continue to update that branch further beyond critical bug fixes.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-10-05**:
Sorry! I'd rather be honest about what's happening than pretend like I'm able to manage support for that many distributions at once.

**Comment by [zl3612](https://answers.ros.org/users/27052/zl3612/) on 2022-10-06**:
Thanks Steve.